# calculate median of several raster files with different extent

Tags: r, raster, median

I'm quite new to R and I have a problem on which I couldn't find a solution so far.
I have a folder of 1000 raster files. I have to get the median of all rasters for each cell.

The files contain NoData Cells (I think therefore they have different extents)
Is there any solution to loop through the folder, adding together all files an getting the median?

```
Error in rep(value, times = ncell(x)) : invalid 'times' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In setValues(x, rep(value, times = ncell(x))) : NAs introduced by coercion
Error in .local(x, i, j, ..., value) : 
  cannot replace values on this raster (it is too large
```

I tried with raster stack, but it doesn't work because of the different extents.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Having NoData and having different extents are two different things. The extent indicates the location of left, right, upper and lower edges of the rectangle, and cells within this rectangle may or may not contain NoData values. If the files do have different extents, do you only want to calculate medians in areas shared by all files (i.e. the intersection of all rasters)?

Comment: The next question is: are the rasters' alignments identical? i.e. do raster edges align with each other?

Comment: Can't you: create a raster for the total extent, overlay each raster to the total extent raster (multiply), create a rasterStack, and run `calc` with median as your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to approach this by `mosaic()`'ing images with different extents and origins but same resolution.

### Create a few rasterLayer objects and export them (to read latter)

```
library('raster')
library('rgdal')

e1 <- extent(0,10,0,10)
r1 <- raster(e1)
res(r1) <- 0.5
r1[] <- runif(400, min = 0, max = 1)
#plot(r1)

e2 <- extent(5,15,5,15)
r2 <- raster(e2)
res(r2) <- 0.5
r2[] <- rnorm(400, 5, 1)
#plot(r2)

e3 <- extent(18,40,18,40)
r3 <- raster(e3)
res(r3) <- 0.5
r3[] <- rnorm(1936, 12, 1)
#plot(r3)

# Write them out
wdata <- '../Stackoverflow/21876858' # your local folder
writeRaster(r1, file.path(wdata, 'r1.tif'),
            overwrite = TRUE)
writeRaster(r2,file.path(wdata, 'r2.tif'),
            overwrite = TRUE)
writeRaster(r3,file.path(wdata, 'r3.tif'),
            overwrite = TRUE)
```

### Read and Mosaic'ing with function

Since raster::mosaic do not accept rasterStack/rasterBrick or lists of rasterLayers, the best approach is to use `do.call`, like [this excellent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287807/how-can-i-create-raster-mosaic-using-list-of-rasters).

To do so, adjust mosaic signature and how to call its arguments with:

```
setMethod('mosaic', signature(x='list', y='missing'), 
          function(x, y, fun, tolerance=0.05, filename=""){
            stopifnot(missing(y))
            args <- x
            if (!missing(fun)) args$fun <- fun
            if (!missing(tolerance)) args$tolerance<- tolerance
            if (!missing(filename)) args$filename<- filename
            do.call(mosaic, args)
          })
```

Let's keep tolerance low here to evaluate any misbehavior of our function.

Finally, the function:

### Mosaic function

```
f.Mosaic <- function(x=x, func = median){
  files <- list.files(file.path(wdata), all.files = F)
  # List  TIF files at wdata folder
  ltif <- grep(".tif$", files, ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE) 
  #lext <- list()
  #1rt <- raster(file.path(wdata, i),
  #            package = "raster", varname = fname, dataType = 'FLT4S')
  # Give an extent area here (you can read it from your first tif or define manually)
  uext <- extent(c(0, 100, 0, 100)) 
  # Get Total Extent Area
  stkl <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(ltif)){
    x <- raster(file.path(wdata, ltif[i]),
                package = "raster", varname = fname, dataType = 'FLT4S')
    xext <- extent(x)
    uext <- union(uext, xext)
    stkl[[i]] <- x
  }
  # Global Area empty rasterLayer
  rt <- raster(uext)
  res(rt) <- 0.5
  rt[] <- NA
  # Merge each rasterLayer to Global Extent area
  stck <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(stkl)){
    merged.r <- merge(stkl[[i]], rt,  tolerance = 1e+6)
    #merged.r <- reclassify(merged.r, matrix(c(NA, 0), nrow = 1))
    stck[[i]] <- merged.r
  }
  # Mosaic with Median
  mosaic.r <- raster::mosaic(stck, fun = func) # using median
  mosaic.r
}
# Run the function with func = median
mosaiced <- f.Mosaic(x, func = median)
# Plot it
plot(mosaiced)
```

[image: mosaiced raster with median]

Possibly far from the best approach but hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help! Unfortunately i got an error message but i can't find where it is: Error in rep(value, times = ncell(x)) : invalid 'times' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In setValues(x, rep(value, times = ncell(x))) : NAs introduced by coercion
Error in .local(x, i, j, ..., value) : cannot replace values on this raster (it is too large any ideas?
thanks again

Comment: did you export r2 and r3 at the very begining `# Write them out`? I just wrote the code for the first...

Comment: @user3327377 could you provide some of your rasters? I didn't understand if you are running on your data or reproducing the code above.

Comment: I'm trying to run it on my own data.

Comment: @user3327377 could you share some of your raster from a dropbox or googledrive?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary because it worked! Obviously i loaded a wrong extent in the first place...thanks a lot for your help Paulo!

Comment: @user3327377. Great! Don't forget to up-vote the answer if you judge it was useful.