# Make raster stack with different extent

Tags: r, stack, spatial, raster, extent

I am in trouble making raster stack which have slightly different extent. The answer (1st one) given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114542/bring-rasters-to-same-extent-by-filling-with-na-in-r) is useful but did not help in my case. For example, I want to make a raster stack using [bio2 raster](https://data.biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/worldclim/v2.0/tif/base/wc2.0_30s_bio.zip) for Australia and [this Australian raster](ftp://203.101.225.64/tern-soils/Products/National_digital_soil_property_maps/AWC/AWC_000_005_05_N_P_AU_NAT_C_20140801.tif). The second raster comes for Australia only and the first one is global. So I cropped the global bio2 raster to the same extent of Australian raster using `crop()` function, but the resultant raster extent (i.e., `bio2.au`) is slightly different (therefore, I cannot make raster using the cropped raster and the Australian raster, `awc`). Sample code is below:

```
library(raster)
awc <- raster("path to Australian raster")
bio2.g <- raster("path to Bio2 global raster")
# crop bio2.g to the same extent of awc
bio2.au <- crop(bio2.g, extent(awc))

# make a raster stack
st <- stack(awc, bio2.au)
Error in compareRaster(x) : different extent
```

I have also tried using `quick=TRUE` within the `stack()` function. But in this case the cell values in `awc` is lost. Note: the size of `awc` raster is 4gb.

```
# first make a list of rasters saved in the computer
li <- list.files("path to file", pattern = ".tif$", full.names = TRUE)
st <- stack(li, quick=TRUE)
st[[1]] # no cell values for awc
```

Your suggestions will be highly appreciated. My ultimate goal is to crop several [bioclim rasters](https://data.biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/worldclim/v2.0/tif/base/wc2.0_30s_bio.zip) to the same extent of [Australian raster](ftp://203.101.225.64/tern-soils/Products/National_digital_soil_property_maps/AWC/AWC_000_005_05_N_P_AU_NAT_C_20140801.tif) `awc` and stack them together so that raster cell values are not lost.

## Edit (after comment of @Cobin):

Below is the attribute of each raster

```
# global raster (bigger raster)
> r
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 21600, 43200, 933120000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : D:\Worldclim2_Bioclim\wc2.0_bio_30s_02.tif 
names       : wc2.0_bio_30s_02 
values      : 0, 37.06667  (min, max)


# Australian raster (smaller raster)
> r1
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 43201, 49359, 2132358159  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.0008333333, 0.0008333333  (x, y)
extent      : 112.8921, 154.0246, -44.00042, -7.999583  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : D:\SoilAWC5cm.EV1.tif 
names       : SoilAWC5cm.EV1 
values      : 2.997789, 27.86114  (min, max)

# new raster, after crop() function is applied
> r2 <- crop(r,extent(r1))
> r2
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 4320, 4936, 21323520  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : 112.8917, 154.025, -44, -8  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpmg9fyF\raster\r_tmp_2018-11-23_164300_11308_65747.grd 
names       : wc2.0_bio_30s_02 
values      : 1.933333, 18.15833  (min, max)

# rebuild r2 to match r1
> r22 <- raster(vals=values(r2),ext=extent(r1), nrows=dim(r1)[1],ncols=dim(r1)[2])

Error in setValues(r, vals) : 
  length(values) is not equal to ncell(x), or to 1
```

Comment: `global raster (bigger raster)` resolution is different from `Australian raster (smaller raster)`. If you want to stack `r1` and `r2`, you should resample the raster insuring they have same `resolution`, `extent`, `crs`. Such as function `resample(r1,r2, method='near')`

Comment: Thank you @Cobin. This trick worked successfully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose that the extent of two raster are differet though the raster masked by `crop` function.You 
should check the both of `awc` and `bio.au` extent base on same reolution, rows and columns. Because I couldn't download data from
hyperlink, I give an example of my own data.

```
r <- raster('/big_raster')
r1 <- raster('/small_raster')
r2 <- crop(r,extent(r1))

r1
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 74, 157, 11618  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.0833333, 0.0833333  (x, y)
extent      : 89.2185, 102.3018, 30.96238, 37.12905  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : D:\D\temp\Rtest\modis8km.tif 
names       : modis8km 
values      : -32768, 32767  (min, max)

r2
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 74, 157, 11618  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent      : 89.25, 102.3333, 31, 37.16667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : g201401a 
values      : -32768, 7789  (min, max)
```

Though r1 and r1 with same resolution and dimension, the extent have tiny offset. It cause stack error.

```
 stack(r1,r2)
 Error in compareRaster(x) : different extent
```

So, you should rebuid the `r2`  to match `r1`:

```
r22 <- raster(vals=values(r2),ext=extent(r1),crs=crs(r1),
                  nrows=dim(r1)[1],ncols=dim(r1)[2])
```

Now `stack(r22,r1)` will be successful.

Comment: Thank you. My `r1` extent is: `112.8921, 154.0246, -44.00042, -7.999583`, and my `r2` extent after cropping is: `112.8917, 154.025, -44, -8`. But I have got the following error: `r22 <- raster(vals=values(r2),ext=extent(r1), nrows=dim(r1)[1], ncols=dim(r1)[2])`. `Error in setValues(r, vals) : length(values) is not equal to ncell(x), or to 1` @Cobin

Comment: The main problem is that the small rasster is not snapping  big raster.The rasters have different rows and collumns  (width and height) after crop.You should show `bio2.au` and `awc` atrribute in question. Maybe `cellFrom` function to crop raster is preciser. @Crayfish

Comment: Thank you. I have now added raster attributes in my main question. @Cobin